# Reading Shared Calendar using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am able to read the events belonging to "My calendars" default folder using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MYEMAILID/events
```

However, I am unable to traverse to events inside shared calendar or folders
the hierarchy is as follows :

My Calendars

- Calendar
- ABC
- XYZ
- MNO

I want to access events from "MNO".

Tried the following but doesn't works:

-- first get the calendargroups

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MYEMAILID/calendarGroups
```

it returns with JSON having details for "Calendar", "ABC" & "XYZ" but nothing for "MNO".

Please note that I imported a .pst in my outlook which as a result of which I see "MNO" folder in outlook with 709 events but nothing in Graph API

Also tried to get the calendars within that group using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/MYEMAILID/calendarGroups('MNO')/calendars
```

Doesn't seem to be working as this request return with an empty JSON object however, in the outlook I can see teh

Comment: +1 same for me. There is a read shared calendars permission, and I have it. Still no calendars listed. Did you find any solution?

Comment: +1 also having similar issue, I am unable to read any other users calendar apart from my own (I have full delegated access granted to my user). Getting 503 error. Anyone fix it?

Comment: Maybe not direct answer to your question, but see my findings here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949159/getting-shared-calendars-with-microsoft-graph-api